# My Dashboard API name it's weird

Tags: metadata-api, dashboard

I have created a Dashboard in my org. The name for it it's "Pipeline Management", but I noticed that the api name it's "pKVGShxaKjvpVXNcMPCHPOUSSeneNd1". Why the api name looks like this?
For my reports, the api name follows the name.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like API name gets auto-generated and it might be something randomly generated id, however editing dashboard API name is currently on roadmap and might be available in near future.

Kindly review limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdgKtUAJ/set-lightning-dashboard-api-name).

You can try below as workaround.

> You can retrieve using the dashboard using the metadata api and the
> autogenerated developer name rename the file and the redeploy, this
> will create a new dashboard with the desired developername.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vinay for taking the time to respond to my question. I didn't know there is an idea to designate the api name for dashboard. Now it makes sense. For anyone having this problem, the workaround mentioned above it's working.